# What word to use for "logically paraphrase"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am an engineer and often work with logical procedures or other constructs that can be written in terms of other procedures. I have to explain how they can be "reinterpreted" in different terms. For example:
The messaging paradigms *publish/subscribe* and *request/response* can both be (*logically paraphrased into* or *written in terms of*) send and receive actions.

However, none of the following the words or phrases fit my context:

- *rewritten*  (too associated with words and language, and *written* does not make sense for these constructs)
- *paraphrased* (same as above)
- *simplified* (it isn't about making it more simple)
- *clarified by writing as* (it isn't about making it clear)

The phrase *written in terms of*, most often used in mathematics, is the closest thing I can think of that suits the context. Another one I thought of is *logically paraphrase* but I feel it is pedantic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Professional programmers have co-opted a term from algebra: ***refactor***.

Comment: "recode" ------

Comment: Are you looking for a word to satisfy a generic technical audience (*represented as*), a mathematical or theoretical computer science audience (*reduced* - in the sense of NP-complete reductions), or the general public (*expressed as*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Philosophers and logicians often talk about natural language sentences being ***regimented*** into a formal language. For example, they will say things like:

> The natural language sentence "All dogs are mammals" is ***regimented*** in first-order logic as ∀x(Dx → Mx).

[***Regiment***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/regiment) means :

> Organize according to a strict, sometimes oppressive system or pattern.

Philosophers and logicians thus use *regiment* to mean "logically paraphrase". [This passage](https://books.google.com/books?id=bYlMCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT34&lpg=PT34&dq=philosophy%20regiment%20in%20first-order%20logic&source=bl&ots=iYZ32XTUDA&sig=LV_aOIiSwIp8UnoXbhJzLZghsIU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYpJT5vKPOAhWJdSYKHTobDbcQ6AEIQzAG#v=onepage&q=philosophy%20regiment%20in%20first-order%20logic&f=false) even goes so far as to explicitly define the term:

> "Regimentation is a form of paraphrase into a logical notation."

For another example, see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=pzf7_sT58PUC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=philosophy%20regiment%20in%20first-order%20logic&source=bl&ots=KVZf1rvCOz&sig=X6TPzTD-_L3JmyZvh1l44sm1c6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYpJT5vKPOAhWJdSYKHTobDbcQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=philosophy%20regiment%20in%20first-order%20logic&f=false).

As far as I know, you can also use this word to describe translating code from one programming language to another, as in:

> The program, when ***regimented*** in Python, looks as follows...

You may also be able to use it to describe translating code from one language into more *primitive* expressions, as in:

> The program, when ***regimented*** using primitives, looks as follows...

In your particular example, you'd have:

> The messaging paradigms "publish/subscribe" and "request/response" can both be ***regimented in terms of*** send and receive actions.